# Parallel.For in Python

Tags: python, windows, parallel-processing

Is there something similar to C#'s excellent Parallel.For in Python? I just want to do a calculation like

```
[simu(c) for c in clusterSizes]
```

in parallel. What is the simplest way to archive that?

PS: I tried joblib, but in my cases it just starts, starts and starts processes until i have to restart my machine.

Comment: Oops, didn't see you already tried joblib. Did you try passing an explicit `n_jobs` parameter?

Comment: yes, I did. Now I actually guess it's related to me starting the program from PyDev in Eclipse

Comment: Are you on Windows? IIRC, joblib on Windows needs the script to be started with an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block for some reason. I don't recall the details, though.

Comment: (>I tried joblib, but in my cases it just starts, starts and starts processes until i have to restart my machine.)
I believe you're running your script in Windows and you met this particular problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405397/python-multiprocessing-continuously-spawns-pythonw-exe-processes-without-doing-a

Comment: yep, this seems to be exactly the problem. Would have never guessed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python 3, there is parallel map in [concurrent.futures](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) (in standard library). I think it was even backported as a module for python 2.7.
**edit** http://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures

As noted in other answer, threads won't help you. Instead you have to use multiple processes.

**edit** from docs it seems as simple as this:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for result in executor.map(simu, clusterSizes)
        pass # save result
```

Answer (score 5):

joblib is based on `multiprocessing` and has the same [problem on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405397/python-multiprocessing-continuously-spawns-pythonw-exe-processes-without-doing-a) that @EwyynTomato points out in the comments: the main entry point to the script must be protected by an `__name__ == "__main__"` check.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(simu)(c) for c in clusterSizes)
    # process result
```

Answer (score 0):

in the `multiprocessing` package, you can create a `Pool` object, and use a `map` method:

see http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

as with joblib, you have to protect the main entry point with `__name__ == "__main__"` otherwise you will create a fork bomb (and will need to restart your computer when importing your script).

The function you are mapping needs to be pickable.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little package that could be of help:

```
from python-parallel-collections import parallel

#equal to [simu(c) for c in clusterSizes]
#performed in parallel using multiple processes
#the results are only evaluated on demand, such as with the call to list below
parallel_gen = parallel(clusterSizes)
lazy_results = parallel_gen.map(simu)
evaluated_results = list(lazy_results)
```

This is Python 2.7 and requires

```
pip install futures

pip install python-parallel-collections
```

let me know what you think
https://github.com/gterzian/Python-Parallel-Collections

Answer (score -3):

Use a different language. Due to the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) Non-IO bound parallelism in Python isn't very efficient.

Comment: IIRC, this is only true for stock Python. Jython doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Besides, whether parallelism is efficient depends on the problem. For coarse-grained parallel processing, Python can be fine.

Comment: Multiprocessing is the standard way to do parallell computations on Python. It works fine. Also, the GIL is an implementation detail specific to CPython.