# Open a background process in python

Tags: python

Actually I do not mean a shell background process like using a "&". I run into a situation that I want to create another process for preparing data (class_data) and a process for computing (class_process). As the (class_data) can generate while (class_process) is processing. I wanna to subclass a thread class just like in java. I just want to the (class_data) to run asynchronous. A sketch maybe as follows:

```
class_data.init_generate()
for i in range(100):
    class_data.generate()
    class_process.process(class_data.data)
    class_data.collect()
```

The generate method may generate a batch data and the collect just wait for the data to be generated and renew the class_data.data to the newly generated.

I am not sure whether I make myself clear, and thanks in advance!

Comment: This a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873713/parallel-for-in-python

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate. Actually I wanna know whether I can just subclass the Process class as what I can do in java.

Answer (score 2):

Python has a [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module which offers synchronization, sharing data between processes, etc.

Comment: Could you give more specific details on it? I tried with apply_async but it could not handle when generate() is a instancemethod rather than a function.

Comment: I don't think you can use it with instance methods in a straight forward way. See the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1816958/15931