# importing and using a module that uses multiprocessing without causing infinite loop on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

I have a module named `multi.py`. If I simply wanted to execute multi.py as a script, then the workaround to avoid crashing on Windows (spawning an infinite number of processes) is to put the multiprocessing code under:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

However, I am trying to import it as a module from another script and call `multi.start()`. How can this be accomplished?

```
# multi.py
import multiprocessing

def test(x):
    x**=2

def start():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()-2)
    pool.map(test, (i for i in range(1000*1000)))
    pool.terminate()
    print('done.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('runs as a script,',__name__)
else:
    print('runs as imported module,',__name__)
```

This is my `test.py` I run:

```
# test.py
import multi
multi.start()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't quite get what you're asking.  You don't need to do anything to prevent this from spawning infinitely many processes.  I just ran it on Windows XP --- imported the file and ran `multi.start()` --- and it completed fine in a couple seconds.

The reason you have to do the `if __name__=="__main__"` protection is that, on Windows, multiprocessing has to import the main script in order to run the target function, which means top-level module code in that file will be executed.  The problem only arises if that top-level module code itself tries to spawn a new process.  In your example, the top level module code doesn't use multiprocessing, so there's no infinite process chain.

Edit: Now I get what you're asking.  You don't need to protect `multi.py`.  You need to protect your main script, whatever it is.  If you're getting a crash, it's because in your main script you are doing `multi.start()` in the top level module code.  Your script needs to look like this:

```
import multi
if __name__=="__main__":
    multi.start()
```

The "protection" is always needed in the *main* script.

Comment: I assume you have called start() from within multi.py? If I create a test.py in the same directory, and do: import multi; multi.start() then I will get a crash.

Comment: Thank you! I got very confused wrongly thinking that it is the module I imported that would be re-imported by new processes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print('runs as a script,',__name__)
else:
  print('runs as imported module,',__name__)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not a problem. The problem is that if you do:
import multi; multi.start()
It will spawn an infinite number of processes (on Windows only).
Discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405397/python-multiprocessing-continuously-spawns-pythonw-exe-processes-without-doing-a