# Why ProcessPoolExecutor on Windows needs __main__ guard when submitting function from another module?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-module

Let's say I have a program

```
import othermodule, concurrent.futures
pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
```

and then I want to say

```
fut = pool.submit(othermodule.foo, 5)
print(fut.result())
```

Official docs say I need to guard these latter two statements with `if __name__ == '__main__'`. It's not hard to do, I would just like to know *why*. `foo` lives in `othermodule`, and it knows that (`foo.__module__ == 'othermodule'`). And 5 is a literal int. Both can be pickled and unpickled without any reference to the module that created the pool. I see no reason why ProcessPoolExecutor has to import it on the other side.

My model is this: you start another python process, pickle `othermodule.foo` and `5`, and send them pickled through some IPC method (Queue, Pipe, whatever). The other process unpickles them (importing `othermodule` of course, to find `foo`'s code), and calls `foo(5)`, sending the result back (again through pickle and some IPC). Obviously my model is wrong, but I would like to know where it is wrong.

Is maybe the only reason, that on Unix this is solved by forking `__main__`, so on Windows (where fork doesn't really work) they did the closest imitation of the procedure, instead of the closest imitation of the intent? In this case, could it be fixed on Windows?

(Yes, I know about [Why does Python's multiprocessing module import __main__ when starting a new process on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175348/why-does-pythons-multiprocessing-module-import-main-when-starting-a-new-pro). In my opinion it answers a slightly different question. But you can try to use its answer to explain to me why the answer to this question must be the same.)

Comment: that's the way, multiprocessing works. if you want another behavior, write your own multiprocessing module.

Comment: I understand that. I would like to know _why_. What are the drawbacks of my model? If it is strictly better than the way multiprocessing works now, probably multiprocessing could be changed to work that way. Of course I  will write my own module, but maybe other people might benefit from it. And the easiest way for it to happen is that mp just works out of the box in situations it didn't work before. Certainly, if there are any disadvantages to such a model, I'd very much like to know about them. But I don't see any.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but now there is a good answer to this.

> Is maybe the only reason, that on Unix this is solved by forking `__main__`, so on Windows (where fork doesn't really work) they did the closest imitation of the procedure, instead of the closest imitation of the intent? In this case, could it be fixed on Windows?

It is my guess that the people who wrote multiprocessing library wrote it under the assumption that os.fork() would be available. On windows, this was bypassed in a hacky way. In fact, still today (2022), python's inbuilt parallelisation modules `multiprocessing` and `concurrent.futures` are a pain to use, mainly because of pickling errors. These modules work the best when the interpreter can be forked, and there is no need to pickle anything.

It can be fixed on Windows. There is a package called `loky` that you can install with pip or conda. It uses an improved pickling module called `cloudpickle` (which also has to be installed) to call the functions from the main module. So, there is no need to import the main module by the child process, and therefore the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard does not have to be used. (Link to github repo of [loky](https://github.com/joblib/loky), and [doc](https://loky.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest)) You can also try the higher level package joblib, which uses loky as its backend and also has the same behaviour.

Loky also has a facility to use a reusable executor (i.e. a pool of processes that will be reused again and again to reduce overhead of spawning). You can check examples of that [here](https://loky.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest#usage). Loky essentially uses the semantics of `ProcessPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures` but has a different implementation underneath.

I will give an example with a single executor (not reusable).

```py
import os

def f(x):
  return os.getpid()

with loky.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as pool:
    jobs = [pool.submit(f,i) for i in range(3)]  # returns Future() instances
    results = [job.result() for job in jobs]  # get results from Future

print(results)
```

Run this on Windows, and it should return the PID of the child processes without any hitch, and without the need to use `if __name__=='__main__'`.

Comment: To run the code above on Windows, `pip install joblib` then `from joblib.parallel import loky`. Alternatively, `pip install loky` then import loky directly.

Comment: @Contango Joblib has its own layer of parallelisation on top of loky, but yes those will work.

Comment: @S R Maiti Yes, you are absolutely correct. I figured that as many people already have joblib installed, it is easier to import it from there rather than also installing the base package. I also suspect that a common loky backend would work better than separate instances if both joblib and futures were being used together, i.e. better they both use the same instance of loki.

Comment: @Contango Yes you are right. It is more efficient to run the same instance of loky because you won't spawn additional processes if you use reusable executor.