# Azure Function Python - ProcessPoolExecutor non-responsive and function host eventually times out

Tags: python, azure-functions

Has anyone worked out the pattern to use concurrent.futures library on an azure function? I am trying to use concurrent.futures to parallelize processing of a time triggered azure function. I'm having trouble debugging the issue since azure function is not responsive code until it hits the timeout value in the case where I guard anm.py per [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801229/why-processpoolexecutor-on-windows-needs-main-guard-when-submitting-function).

[image: azure function times out]

When I don't guard anm.py and simply import the module and kick off the entry process in anm.py when function triggers, I get the following standard issue with the Windows fork issue

> Exception: BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was
>   terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.

It's also worth noting that running the anm.py standalone scales out as expected. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

PS: I understand that Azure Functions have their own [scaling and concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#scaling-and-concurrency) capability but does not seem to address my scenario.