# Can't use multiprocessing in python function

Tags: python

I'm a beginner of python, I'm trying to put multiprocessing into a function, however python gives me an error.

Please refer the original code as below:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
def func1():
    print('test1')
    time.sleep(10)  
def func2():
    print('test2')
    time.sleep(5)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p_func1 = Process(target=func1)
    p_func2 = Process(target=func2)
    p_func1.start()
    p_func2.start()
    p_func1.join()
    p_func2.join()  
    print('done')
```

It runs well and give the correct result I need.

However, when I tried to put the multiprocessing code into function:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def test_multiprocessing():
    def func1():
        print('test1')
        time.sleep(10)  
    def func2():
        print('test2')
        time.sleep(5)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p_func1 = Process(target=func1)
        p_func2 = Process(target=func2)
        p_func1.start()
        p_func2.start()
        p_func1.join()
        p_func2.join()  
        print('done')

test_multiprocessing()
```

Below is error I got, may I know how to fix this issue ? The reason I'd like to put multiprocessing into a funciton is because there is an existing code there, and I don't want to do major change of the code to support multiprocessing.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multipleprocessing.py", line 20, in <module>
    test_multiprocessing()
  File "multipleprocessing.py", line 14, in test_multiprocessing
    p_func1.start()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing
\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing
\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing
\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing
\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing
\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'test_multiprocessing.<locals>.func1'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing
\spawn.py", line 99, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.steal_handle(parent_pid, pipe_handle)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing
\reduction.py", line 87, in steal_handle
    _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Per tested code on Linux, it works. Does that mean Windows Python can't support multiprocessing in function?

Comment: `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'test_multiprocessing.<locals>.func1'` make `func1` and `func2` module-level functions.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct. You shouldn't be keeping `if __name__ == '__main__':` inside the function. Read more about it here [why **name**=="**main**"](http://thepythonguru.com/what-is-if-__name__-__main__/)

try like below,

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def test_multiprocessing():
    def func1():
        print('test1')
        time.sleep(10)  
    def func2():
        print('test2')
        time.sleep(5)

    p_func1 = Process(target=func1)
    p_func2 = Process(target=func2)
    p_func1.start()
    p_func2.start()
    p_func1.join()
    p_func2.join()  
    print('done')

test_multiprocessing()
```

Comment: Hi, Prakash. Thanks for reply. I tried to remove if __name__ == '__main__':, however still got the same error there .

Comment: copy paste the exact code which I answered. It works fine for me. Also take care of indentation

Comment: Tried to copy and paste your code, still got same error. I'm using Python 3.6.5, is there any version dependency ?

Comment: should not be a problem. Looks like some access is being denied. If you are windows, try running the `cmd` as administrator and run your program

Comment: I tested your code on Linux, it works. But in Windows, it still has the same problem. So, Windows python can't support multiprocessing in a function?

Comment: exactly.. some system level permissions issue I suppose. Give python executable the required access and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

a bit correction in @Prakash answer. You need to call function inside from  `if __name__== "__main__"`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175348/why-does-pythons-multiprocessing-module-import-main-when-starting-a-new-pro?noredirect=1&lq=1), explained well !!

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time


def func1():
    print('test1')
    time.sleep(10)

def func2():
    print('test2')
    time.sleep(5)

def test_multiprocessing():
    p_func1 = Process(target=func1)
    p_func2 = Process(target=func2)
    p_func1.start()
    p_func2.start()
    p_func1.join()
    p_func2.join()
    print('done')

if __name__== "__main__":
    test_multiprocessing()
```

Another way is you can bound method to a class because [functions are only picklable if they are defined at the top-level of a module.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-pickling-error) as below:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

class Foo:

    def func1(self):
        print('test1')
        time.sleep(10)

    def func2(self):
        print('test2')
        time.sleep(5)

    def test_multiprocessing(self):
        p_func1 = Process(target=self.func1)
        p_func2 = Process(target=self.func2)
        p_func1.start()
        p_func2.start()
        p_func1.join()
        p_func2.join()
        print('done')

if __name__== "__main__":
    f=Foo()
    f.test_multiprocessing()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Chanda, it works on Windows. If I need to put `func1`, `func2` into function `test_multiprocessing`, is that possible?

Comment: @Knight please see updated answer. Directly putting `func1`,`func2` into function`test_multiprocessing` would give you pickling error. You can use class instead.