# Python: Multiprocessing running portion of code that it shouldn't

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, mpmath

I was sort of playing around with multiprocessing and different math libraries to calculate pi and wanted to know how much faster was it with or without multiprocessing by implementing `time.perf_counter()`. mp.Pool maps 20 threads as the same with my CPU threads count, while processing main, it also processed

```
etime = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Time Used: {etime - stime:0.4f}sec.\n")
```

which prints it 20 times.

Result excluded print in solve:

```
...
...
...

Time Used: 0.0001sec.

Time Used: 0.0001sec.

Time Used: 0.0000sec.

Time Used: 15.0268sec.
```

```
import time
import numpy as np
from mpmath import mp
import multiprocessing as mps

stime = time.perf_counter()
mp.dps = 50
accuracy = 6000000
R = 1


def solve(a):
    n = a
    theta = 360 / n
    rad = mp.radians(theta/2)
    print(n*R*mp.sin(rad))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mps.Pool(mps.cpu_count())
    pool.map(solve, range(1, accuracy))
    pool.close()
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()


etime = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Time Used: {etime - stime:0.4f}sec.\n")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Python's multiprocessing module import \_\_main\_\_ when starting a new process on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175348/why-does-pythons-multiprocessing-module-import-main-when-starting-a-new-pro)

Comment: No, it's not related to my topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: To fix your problem, just indent the last two lines.

The `multiprocessing` library actually runs the entire Python script in each thread. As an experiment run `python` in the same directory as the program and try importing it. You will notice that the bottom two statements will run even though the `solve` function doesn't

Therefore, anything that is not in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block will be run by each thread. The `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement tells Python to only run this code in the main thread.

To solve your problem, you need to add the bottom two lines into the `if` statement.