# Multiprocessing in Python Issue

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I'm trying multiprocessing in python but can't seem to get it to work.

The input file is as follows:

[image]

And the code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
import time
import datetime


start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
df_main = []
df_main = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df_file = []

def growth_calculator(Type):
    values = [Type]
    global df_temp, df_file
    df_temp = df_main[df_main.Type.isin(values)]
    df_temp = df_temp[['Company', 'Type']]
    print(df_temp)
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.Process(target=growth_calculator('Quarterly'))
    multiprocessing.Process(target=growth_calculator('Annual'))
    multiprocessing.Process(target=growth_calculator('Monthly'))
    end_time = datetime.datetime.now()

print("Time Taken -", end_time-start_time)
```

The output should take around 10-11 seconds, but it's taking 30 seconds. So, clearly, multiprocessing isn't working.

Could you please point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not uncommon for the overhead of parallelism to dominate over any benefits. You probably need to add more debugging details (including representative sample data) if you really want to figure out where the time is spent.

Comment: What platform (Linux? Windows? Something else?) are you running under? You should always tag your question with the platform when you have multiprocessing questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass target arguments as `args=` keyword for the Process init (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process).  Otherwise your function is evaluated before instantiating process, which leads to single-process performance.

Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
import time
import datetime


start_time = datetime.datetime.now()


def growth_calculator(Type):

    print(Type)
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=growth_calculator,args=('Quarterly',))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=growth_calculator,args=('Annual',))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=growth_calculator,args=('Monthly',))
   
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    print('started')
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    end_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    print("Time Taken -", end_time-start_time)
```

Comment: This is perfect and worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

I have one follow up question though. I'm adding a print statement below all the mentioned lines of code, unindented. It's printing thrice, even though it's not part of any loop.

Any idea why that is?

Comment: it is because when multiprocessing creates processes, they also run whole program, to make your code accessible. They have `__name__` modified, so only parent process will execute parts where `__name__`==`'__main__'`. It allows to prevent 'fork bomb' of your app. If you put print unindented, it is executed by all copies of program (so it should be 4 times, actually). See i.e. discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175348/why-does-pythons-multiprocessing-module-import-main-when-starting-a-new-pro thread.

Comment: Got it. Thanks much!