# Combining python's multiprocessing module with a prime number function

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using the python multiprocessing/pool module to compare program running times of a function that checks if a number is a prime. I can get the prime function to work by itself, but can't seem to merge the two so they work together. The pool function below:

```
import math import time
import multiprocessing from multiprocessing import Pool

def pool_process(f,data,pool_size):

    tp1 = time.time()
    pool = Pool(processes = pool_size)
    result = pool.map(f, data)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    #enter code here
    print("Results", result)
    print("Overall Time:", (time.time()-tp1))
```

The function I am using to check if a number is a prime is the following:

```
def check_prime(num):

    t1 = time.time()
    res = False

    if num > 0:

        for i in range(2,num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                print(num,"is not a prime number")
                print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
                print("Time:", (time.time()-t1))
                break
        else:
            print(num,"is a prime number")
            print("Time:", time.time()-t1) 
            res = True

    return res
```

Then I am calling the pool_process function

```
data = 15488801
pool_process(check_prime, data, 1)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What is `def pool_process(f,data,pool_size)` and why is it in your code? What is `f` and where is _that_?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, as this is code I have been given and I have to make it work with the prime function.
I have seen a similar example where result=p.map(sqrt,[1,2,3]) if that helps

Comment: So where's `f`?

Comment: What is the prime function? How are you *calling the code above?* We don't know what you don't show us, if you can't get something to work, please provide a [mcve] and also, a description of how it doesn't work.

Comment: I have the following comment in my notes:
#  f is a function that takes a single argument
My best guess is that f(x) is the prime function( checks if the number is a prime) and that by calling f in the pool_process function I am invoking f(x).

Comment: So, from what I can gather, you are trying to use your `pool_process` function with some "prime function" as `f`, but how can we know how the prime function isn't working if you haven't provided it?

Comment: Cool. So, what exactly is the problem you are encountering? Are you getting an error somewhere?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm getting the following error: `'int' object is not iterable
`

Comment: Because you need to pass `pool.map` an *iterable*, like a `list`

Answer (score 0):

`data` in the third code snippet needs to be a list.

The variable `data` is fed into `pool_process` as second argument.

```
data = [15488801]
pool_process(check_prime, data, 1)
```

In there it is given to [`Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) as argument to iterate over.

```
def pool_process(f,data,pool_size):
    # ...
    result = pool.map(f, data)
```

After I put that integer into a list (and correcting the `import` statements) the code runs fine on my machine.

Comment: I did try it with the data variable in the form of a list `data = [15488801]` but it just gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Have you tried with a lower value for testing, e.g. `data = [11]`?

Comment: Yes, just tried it. Infinite loop. Also tried it with `data = [1, 2, 3, 4]` just to be thorough. What did you mean by "correcting the `import` statements"?

Comment: It runs if `data = ()`

Comment: The `import` statements in first snippet lack two new lines, but I guess these just got lost during copy-pasting. When I run locally, I get this as output: `15488801 is a prime number / Time: 1.539153814315796 / Results [True] / Overall Time: 1.6721937656402588` I copied all your code to a file and run locally with python3. Have you tried executing only that specific method, e.g. with `print(check_prime(15488801))`?

Comment: @Mariyana Are you on Windows?

Comment: @creativecoding let me guess, are you *not* on Windows?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm using Ubuntu 17.04. Are you hinting that [platform-dependent starting methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) might be an issue? _Starting a process using this ["spawn"] method is rather slow compared to using "fork" or "forkserver"._

Comment: @creativecoding no, I'm thinking the lack of `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367835/importing-and-using-a-module-that-uses-multiprocessing-without-causing-infinite/

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have Windows 10. I also tried using it on Ubuntu with my VirtualBox and I get the same error. I have ran it on both jupyter notebook and through IDLE. Throws the same error every time. If the number is in list form it creates an infinite loop. If the number is not in a list form it says `'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: @Mariyana yes, as I explained, it will always throw that error because `map` expects an *iterable*, like a list. That infinite loop is probably because you haven't used an `if __name__ ==  '__main__':` guard, which is *required* on Windows.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry I was just reiterating the outputs I’ve been getting. I will include the guard you mentioned but I’m not sure where it’s meant to go in the code? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Mariyana the part that calls `pool_process(check_prime, data, 1)` needs to be guarded. Realize, `multiprocessing` is essentially opening up a bunch of Python interpreters, and running your code. In Windows, due to the way the operating system branchese processes, it has to *copy everything*, which unfortunately, means that your code enters an infinite loop. Just follow the examples in the `multiprocessing` docs.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga placing `if __name__=="__main__":` immediately after defining the pool_processes function worked! Thank you for your help!
@creativecoding thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad, things worked out! :-) @juanpa.arrivillaga You might want to create a separate answer based such that it can be marked as the solution.